# Read latency stats in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

What is the difference between read latency and local read latency in tablestats.
In my 2-node cluster,while the local read latency are almost cat par,there is significant variance in 'read latency'.What does that indicate and what may cause this?

Answer (score 2):

"Local read latency" is for specific table. The "Read Latency" is for keyspace it's aggregate of latencies for all tables in the given keyspace (but may depend on version - see [CASSANDRA-11226](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11226))

In your case you need to check all tables in given keyspace to find what table may influence the aggregate.

Comment: So read latency involves system tables too - is that a reason why I would sometimes see read latency scoring better than local read latency.Which metric would give the latency of a node from a client perspective then - read + network + node allocation routine.

Comment: You can get via JMX the `CoordinatorReadLatency` metric (see http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/metrics.html), but this will give you only cluster side metric. Some drivers expose client-side metrics, like this: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/metrics/ or for queries: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/logging/#logging-query-latencies